# Recovering Audio from Unrecorded Call

Tags: call-recording

On my Asus Zenfone 5, how can I recover/playback the audio of a previous call that I did not record?

Comment: If you would like an audio recording of a call you did not record, you want something that does not exist, since you did not make it.

Comment: Speak to the NSA maybe?

Comment: Short answer: You cannot. @Chahk, that depends on whether the OP is in America or not.

Answer (score 4):

Without a phone that automatically records everything (I doubt you could carry it, the storage unit would be pretty heavy), if you didn't choose to record the call while it was ongoing, there's nothing you can do to get it back.

Well, you could try the special "TARDIS Recorder" app. You can only download it from either Gallifrey's cell network or from The Doctor's sonic screwdriver, or you can get it for free from the restaurant at the end of the universe. Beware the Hounds of Tindalos who might pursue you through the corners you cut!

Comment: As comical as this answer is... In all good conscious, I have to down vote it.

Comment: @acejavelin if you feel you must...

Comment: @acejavelin I will +1 this answer thanks to both its comedy and because of the fact that it also properly answers the question. Although I recommend changing the order of the paragraphs, as this otherwise might be misleading just going by the first line. I will edit the answer to that effect.

Comment: I added a bit more comedy and literary references for **zat effect!**

Comment: The edited answer is much better and retains the comedy, I will switch it to a +1